# C++ global variable in multiple files

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I have a Class Button, that includes a class ButtonManager, which managers buttons.

Then I have 2 functions that handle things, 1 is like login window with few buttons, the second one is the game menu itself, which also has buttons in it.

However, the two windows take quite a lot of lines, and so I decided to split it to multiple .cpp files, where I just call stuff from main.

The problem is, I need to include the button class in both .cpps, and main and the secondary cpp also include some `dummy.h` which contains the declaration of the common function rendering the menu.

The main issue is, that the ButtonManager has a global variable and when compiling it says that the symbol is already defined.

Example code:

a.h(acts as if it was the Button Manager header file):

```
#ifndef _ABC_
#define _ABC_

struct A{
    int b;
}a = A();

#endif
```

side.h(lets say this is for main game window):

```
#ifndef _SIDE_H_
#define _SIDE_H_

int callSomething();

#endif    //_SIDE_H_:
```

side.cpp:

```
#include "side.h"
#include "abc.h"

#include <iostream>

int callSomething()
{
    std::cout << a.b << "\n";
    return a.b;
}
```

main.cpp:

```
#include "abc.h"
#include "side.h"
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    callSomething();
    std::cin.get();
}
```

When I try to compile it, the compiler complains:

`1>side.obj : error LNK2005: "struct A a" (?a@@3UA@@A) already defined in DynamicDispatch.obj
1>H:\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\example\Debug\dynamicdispatch.exe : fatal error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found`

All help is appreciated

Comment: I seached, and I know about `extern` keyword, but how do you apply `extern` keyword on variable defined in that way? I only came so far that if I remove the `#include "abc.h"` from `main.cpp` it works, but then I cant use `struct A` in `main.cpp`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `a.h` declare the variable as

```
struct A{
    int b;
};
extern struct A a;
```

Then in main.cpp define it once:

```
struct A a;
int main()
{
    //...
}
```

Comment: thank you, that works, even tho I thought that it would be possible to only have it only type it once, but looks thats impossible; edit: you have a typo in `main` hehe

Comment: @0x499602D2 i fixed it. it said `mian`